# ARM7TDMI does not support requested special purpose register

Tags: gcc, assembly, arm

I need to convert some code compiled with ARMASM to gcc(code sourcery GCC-4.6.2 eabi). I use a ARM7TDMI and my compilations arguments are

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc -c -march=armv4t -mcpu=arm7tdmi -mlittle-endian -g -O1
```

(I omitted the -I and -D arguments...)

In one of my files I have this code that won't compile :

```
extern inline void ngEnable( void)
{
    int tmp;
    asm volatile(
        "msr %[tmp], CPSR\n\t"
        "bic %[tmp], %[tmp], #0xC0\n\t"
        "msr CPSR_c, %[tmp]"
        : [tmp] "+r" (tmp)
    );
}
```

I get this error :

```
C:\DOCUME~1\MALLAR~1.ISC\LOCALS~1\Temp\ccA9cCgQ.s: Assembler messages:
C:\DOCUME~1\MALLAR~1.ISC\LOCALS~1\Temp\ccA9cCgQ.s:267: Error: selected processor does not support requested special purpose register -- `msr r3,CPSR'
make: *** [cdbini.o] Error 1
```

according to this post [Re: trouble building linux-linaro-3.0-2011.08-0](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.linux.linaro.devel/6500)  (I build on windows, but the problem could be the same?) I'm already using the workaround of not using -march=all...

Any idea of what my problem is?

Comment: Do you compile it with thumb or arm instruction set? Thumb mode might have some limitation with accessing registers so you might try arm instructions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To read a special purpose register, you should use the `mrs` instruction:

```c
extern inline void ngEnable(void)
{
  int tmp;
  asm volatile(
    "mrs %[tmp], CPSR\n\t"
    "bic %[tmp], %[tmp], #0xC0\n\t"
    "msr CPSR_c, %[tmp]"
    : [tmp] "=r" (tmp)
  );
}
```

After this fix, the code works for me just fine.

Also, since you don't use the value of `tmp`, and you don't in fact even set it, you should use `=r` (output only) instead of `+r` (input-output).

Comment: Thanks the code compile fine now. I will have a closer look on your changes!

Comment: You're welcome. By the way, if you think the answer is good, you can upvote it, apart from accepting it ;)